# First and last day of last month in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to find the first and last day of last month in Redshift. However, most of the postgresql features like `date_trunc` do not seem to work. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Amazon RedShift does support `date_trunc()`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In Redshift, you can use `date_trunc()` (See [online documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html)).

For the first day of last month:

```
select date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month'
```

Or:

```
select date_add(month, -1, date_trunc('month', current_date))
```

For the last day of last month:

```
select date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 day'
```

Comment: I get the following error when using the above code. Error:  Interval values with month or year parts are not supported. Do you have a recommended way around this problem?

Comment: @Phil . . . The question was originally tagged with Postgres.  I updated the answer.

Comment: just to clarify `select date_add(month, -1, date_trunc('month', current_date))` should be `select date_add('month', -1, date_trunc('month', current_date))`

Answer (score 9):

Or for last day in moth you can use a LAST_DAY Function. :)
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LAST_DAY.html

`select last_day(current_date)`

Comment: so odd there isn't a FIRST_DAY.  and yeah, `date_trunc` does that...but the result is not formatted the same as LAST_DAY w/o a second formatting function. :(